# How to use a %in% condition in the R which function?

Tags: r, conditional-statements

I have a simple task, which I can do in loads of line of individual code, but I would like to simplify it as it will take a long time in the future.

my task is to transform 100's of columns of a data frame in to factors and re label accordingly.

with just a subset of my data, I tried to create a list of variables as the 12 variables have different prefixes at each wave (year of collection, the code I ended up using was:

```
ghq <-c("scghqa", "scghqb", "scghqc", "scghqd", "scghqe", "scghqf", "scghqg",
        "scghqh", "scghqi", "scghqj", "scghqk", "scghql")
waves <- c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e")
ghqa <-  paste0(waves[1], sep = "_", ghq[1:12]) 
ghqb <-  paste0(waves[2], sep = "_", ghq[1:12]) 
ghqc <-  paste0(waves[3], sep = "_", ghq[1:12]) 
ghqd <-  paste0(waves[4], sep = "_", ghq[1:12]) 
ghqe <-  paste0(waves[5], sep = "_", ghq[1:12]) 
ghqv <- c(ghqa, ghqb, ghqc, ghqd, ghqe)
```

I tried this in a for loop, but I could not get it to produce the output in a list or character vector (only a matrix seemed to work), see the code for that at the bottom of this question, if you are curious.

From here to be able to use apply, I need to know the positions of these columns in the dataframe
apply(data[c(indexes of cols), 2, lfactor(c(values in the factor), levels =c(levels they will correspond to), labels=c(text labels to be attached to each level))
**NOTE:** I put this here because perhaps I am going the wrong way about things by trying to use apply.

so to identify the columns I want drom the data i used

```
head(dat[colnames(dat) %in% ghqv]) # produced the data for the 60 rows I want
length(dat[colnames(dat) %in% ghqv]) # 60 (as expected)
```

so I tried:

```
which(dat[colnames(dat) %in% ghqv])

Error in which(dat[colnames(dat) %in% ghqv]) : 
  argument to 'which' is not logical
```

How can I transform this to a logical please? as any time I use == with %in% it does not seem to recognise it

To try to help simplify this, with the silly variable names, I created the same issue in the mt cars data set:

```
cars <- mtcars
vars <- c("mpg", "qsec")
head(cars[colnames(cars) %in% vars])
which(cars[colnames(cars) %in% vars])

Error in which(cars[colnames(cars) %in% vars]) : 
  argument to 'which' is not logical
```

Any assistance would be very welcomed, thank you

Just as an aside; the for loop i couldn't change to create a single vector which appended

```
vars <- data.frame(matrix(nrow = 12, ncol = 5)) # we will create a container
colnames(vars) <- c("wave1", "wave2", "wave3", "wave4", "wave5")
rownames(vars) <- c("ghq1", "ghq2", "ghq3", "ghq4", "ghq5",
                     "ghq6", "ghq7", "ghq8", "ghq9", "ghq10",
                     "ghq11", "ghq12")
for(i in 1:5){
  a <- paste(waves[i], ghqv[1:12], sep = "_")
  vars[,i] <- a
  print(a) # we print it to see in console 
}
```

Comment: `dat[which(colnames(dat) %in% ghqv)]`.

Comment: `dat[colnames(dat) %in% ghqv]` gives you the data where that condition is true, `colnames(dat) %in% ghqv` gives you just the condition

Comment: Thank you both so much! I really appreciate your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### You're passing an entire data frame to `which()`

`which(cars[colnames(cars) %in% vars])` is running `which` on `cars[colnames(cars) %in% vars]`, which is a substet of the `cars` data.frame (incidentally, `cars[colnames(cars %in% vars]` is identical to `cars[vars]`

If you just want the indeces of matching columns, run:

`which(colnames(cars) %in% vars)`

#### There's probably a better way to do what you want to do

I would run

```r
require(dplyr)

mutate(cars, across(all_of(vars), factor)) %>%
rename_at(vars, some_function_that_renames_columns)
```